# Intellij - deploy on wildfly throws exception java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, wildfly-8

I am new to maven and wildfly so I'm not sure if I have everything setup correctly. I am using intellij 14 community edition.

I have a maven project with pom file like bellow:

```
<project>
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>root</groupId>
   <version>1.0</version>
   <artifactId>project</artifactId>
   <packaging>pom</packaging>
   <name>project</name>
   <modules>
      <module>projects</module>
      <module>primary-source</module>
      <module>servlets</module>
      <module>ejbs</module>
      <module>ear</module>
   </modules>
   <properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
      <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
   </properties>
   <repositories>
      <repository>
         <id>JBoss Repository</id>
         <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
      </repository>
      <repository>
         <id>Junit Repository</id>
         <url>http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit/4.11</url>
      </repository>
   </repositories>

   <build>
      <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
      <pluginManagement>
         <plugins>
            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
               <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>1.1.0.Alpha4</version>
               <configuration>
                  <port>9991</port>
                  <skip>false</skip>
               </configuration>
               <executions>
                  <execution>
                     <goals>
                     <goal>deploy</goal>
                     </goals>
                  </execution>
               </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.18.1</version>
            </plugin>
         </plugins>
      </pluginManagement>
   </build>
   <dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>root.project.projects</groupId>
            <artifactId>logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>root.project</groupId>
            <artifactId>primary-source</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>root.project.servlets</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <type>war</type>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>root.project</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejbs</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <type>ejb</type>
         </dependency>
      </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>junit</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
         <version>4.11</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
         <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
         <version>2.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
         <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
         <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
         <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <!-- Import the Servlet API -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
         <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>

   </dependencies>
</project>
```

I am able to build the maven application with success but the problem appears when I type in "mvn wildfly:deploy" in Intellij terminal view. Then I get the following error.

```
Error executing FORCE_DEPLOY
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.wildfly.plugin.common.DeploymentExecutionException: Error executing FORCE_DEPLOY
        at org.wildfly.plugin.deployment.standalone.StandaloneDeployment.execute(StandaloneDeployment.java:175)
        at org.wildfly.plugin.deployment.AbstractDeployment.executeDeployment(AbstractDeployment.java:138)
        at org.wildfly.plugin.deployment.AbstractDeployment.doExecute(AbstractDeployment.java:163)
        at org.wildfly.plugin.deployment.AbstractAppDeployment.doExecute(AbstractAppDeployment.java:70)
        at org.wildfly.plugin.deployment.AbstractDeployment.execute(AbstractDeployment.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\YAS\behind-the-scene\yas-mapp\target\project.maven-project
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:79)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:230)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
        at java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(Files.java:3152)
        at org.wildfly.plugin.deployment.standalone.StandaloneDeployment.addContent(StandaloneDeployment.java:191)
        at org.wildfly.plugin.deployment.standalone.StandaloneDeployment.createDeployOperation(StandaloneDeployment.java:201)
        at org.wildfly.plugin.deployment.standalone.StandaloneDeployment.execute(StandaloneDeployment.java:136)
        ... 26 more
```

I know that the target folder is missing, but I can't figure out why. I thought after a clean and install command the target file should be created. can someone help me?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your */target* directory is missing because you're running the deployer plugin in the context of parent pom with **packaging** tag set to **pom**. The plugin doesn't know what module you want to deploy. If you want all modules to be deployed as one application, probably you should create another one, where a package consist of all modules will be created and deployed.